# Conan: Combining conanfile.py recipe with conanfile.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, conan, xtensor

A header-only library dependency I plan to use does not provide a conan recipe.

I am trying to make one myself and combine it with the existing conanfile.txt dependencies I have.

In detail:
I am calling `conan 1.60` from within cmake (see [cmake-conan](https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan)) to load these dependencies:
`conanfile.txt`

```
[requires]
gtest/1.13.0
pybind11/2.10.4
range-v3/0.12.0
fmt/10.1.1
xtensor/0.24.3

[generators]
cmake
cmake_find_package
cmake_paths
```

I would also like to use conan to pull in [xtensor-python](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor-python) which provides pybind11 bindings for xtensor. Since this repo does not have a conan-recipe I created my own (perhaps faulty) by adapting xtensor's recipe:

```py
import os
import textwrap

from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.files import apply_conandata_patches, get, save
from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeToolchain, CMake, cmake_layout, CMakeDeps


class XTensorPythonRecipe(ConanFile):
    name = "xtensor-python"
    license = "BSD 3-Clause"
    url = "https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor-python"
    description = "Python bindings for the xtensor C++ multi-dimensional array library."
    topics = ("numpy", "multidimensional-arrays", "tensors")
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    package_type = "header-library"

    exports_sources = "include/*"

    def source(self):
        get(
            self,
            **self.conan_data["sources"][self.version],
            destination=self.source_folder,
            strip_root=True,
        )

    def build(self):
        apply_conandata_patches(self)
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires("xtensor/0.24.3")
        self.requires("pybind11/2.10.4")

    def layout(self):
        cmake_layout(self)

    def package(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.install()

    def package_id(self):
        self.info.clear()

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_file_name", "xtensor-python")
        self.cpp_info.set_property("cmake_target_name", "xtensor-python")
        self.cpp_info.set_property("pkg_config_name", "xtensor-python")
        self.cpp_info.bindirs = []
        self.cpp_info.libdirs = []

        # TODO: to remove in conan v2 once cmake_find_package* generators removed
        self.cpp_info.build_modules["cmake_find_package"] = [self._module_file_rel_path]
        self.cpp_info.build_modules["cmake_find_package_multi"] = [
            self._module_file_rel_path
        ]

    def _create_cmake_module_alias_targets(self, module_file, targets):
        content = ""
        for alias, aliased in targets.items():
            content += textwrap.dedent(
                f"""\
                if(TARGET {aliased} AND NOT TARGET {alias})
                    add_library({alias} INTERFACE IMPORTED)
                    set_property(TARGET {alias} PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES {aliased})
                endif()
            """
            )
        save(self, module_file, content)

    @property
    def _module_file_rel_path(self):
        return os.path.join("lib", "cmake", f"conan-official-{self.name}-targets.cmake")
```

The sources are pulled from a `conandata.yml` file.

My question now is: **how do I combine this recipe with my existing requirements in the `conanfile.txt`?**

Currently the cmake call to conan does this:

```
for CONANFILE in [deps/xtensor-python/conanfile.py, deps/conanfile.txt]:
    conan install CONANFILE -pr=default -s BUILDSETTINGS
```

in each iteration of the loop this gives me a conanbuildinfo.cmake file that I include, but ends up in errors of duplicated targets:

```
CMake Error at cmake-build-debug/conanbuildinfo.cmake:509 (add_library):
  add_library cannot create imported target "CONAN_PKG::pybind11" because
  another target with the same name already exists.
```

since both recipes pull in e.g. pybind11 and define the targets individually.

Is my approach wrong and if so, what is the correct approach to doing this?

Comment: Is there a reason you use the deprecated version 1.6?

Comment: cmake-conan support is still experimental for conan 2.0

Comment: That's a reason to remove cmake-conan, not to use a deprecated version of Conan. Do you even use cmake-conan? It's trivial to replace cmake-conan in most projects.

Comment: Calling conan 1.60 deprecated is simply wrong, it was updated just a month ago to 1.60.2 and works just fine for all intents and purposes. 2.0 was released only 6 months ago after all. Yes, I am using cmake-conan as I stated in my question. I plan to keep using it, as it is a great convenience wrapper.

Comment: The Conan team calls all versions 1.x legacy versions and all functions that are dropped for version 2 deprecated functions. That's the official naming. Yes, you can provide updates for deprecated versions.

Comment: I see, that's fair enough then. Yet, moving to 2.0 is just not on my todo list atm, at least not while their own wrappers haven't done so.

Comment: cmake-conan for 1.X is version 0.18.1, it was never declared stable, and in fact broke a couple of times. The integration for Conan 2.0 in cmake-conan is fully transparent, not needing to modify the ``CMakeLists.txt``, so it has less risk of breaking than previous 0.18.1 for Conan 1.X: https://github.com/conan-io/cmake-conan/tree/develop2

Comment: You should not try workarounds to combine conanfile.txt with a .py recipe, instead, move .txt content to .py file. The conanfile.py can be use as conanfile.txt too, only to install dependencies. If you keep both, there will be a workaround to maintain and 2 files.

Comment: @uilianries i was thinking along this line too, but cant find information on how to connect a MyPkgRecipe class with the dependency XTensorPythonRecipe I mentioned in my post.

Comment: Sadly there are lot of breaking changes on conan 2, and packages are not directly compatible. i understand the need to stays on 1.x.